# How to avoid changing local variables value to change when not directly accesing it?

Tags: c#

I have this code that changes the value between 2 positions in a bidimensional array, I have an original bidimensional array called  `LocalMatrix`, I create a copy of it, and then work with that copy to avoid changing the original values, but everytime I change the value of the copy, it changes the values in the original array, which I never access.

Here's the `Matrix` class, it has an `InnerMatrix` which is a regular `int[3,3]` :

```
public class Matrix
    {
        public int[,] InnerMatrix { get; set; }        
        public double Fn { get; set; }        

        public Matrix()
        {
            InnerMatrix = new int[3,3];
        }
```

And this is the implementation:

```
public class Solver
    {
        private Matrix LocalMatrix;

        public Solver(Matrix matrix)
        {
            LocalMatrix = matrix;
            Explore();            
        }

        private void Explore()
        {
            Position zero = FindZero();
            List<Position> possibleMoves = PossibleMoves.GetPossibleMoves(zero);
            PossibleStates(possibleMoves, zero);
        }

        private List<Matrix> PossibleStates(List<Position> possibleMoves, Position zero)
        {
            List<Matrix> list = new List<Matrix>();            
            int carry;

            possibleMoves.ForEach( position => 
            {                
                Matrix matrix = LocalMatrix;
                carry = LocalMatrix.InnerMatrix[position.i, position.j];

//Here when I change the recently created matrix values, it changes the LocalMatrix values

                matrix.InnerMatrix[zero.i, zero.j] = carry;
                matrix.InnerMatrix[position.i, position.j] = 0;

                list.Add(matrix);
            });

            PrintPossibleStates(list);

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to understand the difference between value and reference types. You didn't copy the array, you copied the reference to the array.

Comment: why don't you Clone() InnterMatrix?

Comment: @Arphile Thank you so much, I did it with Clone(), works perfectly!

Comment: your welcome. :) I'm happy to hear that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the changes to localmatrix is when you set matrix = to LocalMatrix, its not copy the object, but really just setting matrix to the reference of LocalMatrix.

You need to create a new matrix with the values of localmatrix to keep their values separate.

Comment: How could I do this? 
I tried this: 
```Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.InnerMatrix = LocalMatrix.InnerMatrix;```

Comment: So this worked:
```matrix.InnerMatrix = LocalMatrix.InnerMatrix.Clone() as int[,];```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

Matrix matrix = LocalMatrix;

Does not copy the Matrix instance, it assigns the value of LocalMatrix to the variable matrix which, because it is a class type, is a pointer to that object. What you have done is create two variables, LocalMatrix and matrix, that point to the same object in memory.  What you need is a method to clone the Matrix class, using the Array.Clone method to copy the values of the InnerMatrix array into a new array.

Comment: Yes thank you, but it's with Clone(), CopyTo() is for unidimensional arrays only.

Comment: You are right, I changed my answer after I noticed it was a multidimensional array. If your matrix class is going to become more complex, it might be a good idea to create a dedicated Clone method to perform the operations required to copy the object

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone for the reference and value clarification, the solution is to clone the data of the `InnerMatrix` this way:

`matrix.InnerMatrix = LocalMatrix.InnerMatrix.Clone() as int[,];`